# Change Actual position after animation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm using animation in my app. There is one image Where I implement animation.
But after animation I'm not able to click on image. I searched and read stackoverflow answer about this and finally found that animation only dram raw pixels. So, I need to move view on actual position. I found that this is possible by setting layout param after animation. But I don't know how I can do that. Here is my code that I'm using for animation.

**anim.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%p"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="500" />
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0.45"
    android:toYScale="0.45" >
</scale>

 </set>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/capture_picture" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
  ImageView btnCameraPic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturePicture);
  Animation animation= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.animation);
  btnCameraPic.startAnimation(animation);

  btnCameraPic.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
{
@Override
public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) 
{
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) 
{
}           
@Override
public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) 
{
}
});
```

How can I set new Layout param after animation because I don't know what are new new param is there any way to get these new param from **animation.xml** file and set it to **btnCameraPic** inside `AnimationListener`.

I read many question on stackoverflow but mostly are used animation on java class instead of from xml file. Can anyone please let me know what are the new param after animation ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add following line in anim.xml file.

```
android:fillAfter = "true"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**

You should use **property animations**.

**Reason:**

> How Property Animation Differs from View Animation
>   The view animation system provides the capability to only animate View objects, so if you wanted to animate non-View objects, you have to implement your own code to do so. The view animation system is also constrained in the fact that it only exposes a few aspects of a View object to animate, such as the scaling and rotation of a View but not the background color, for instance.
>
> Another disadvantage of the view animation system is that it only modified where the View was drawn, and not the actual View itself. For instance, if you animated a button to move across the screen, the button draws correctly, but the actual location where you can click the button does not change, so you have to implement your own logic to handle this.
>
> With the property animation system, these constraints are completely removed, and you can animate any property of any object (Views and non-Views) and the object itself is actually modified. The property animation system is also more robust in the way it carries out animation. At a high level, you assign animators to the properties that you want to animate, such as color, position, or size and can define aspects of the animation such as interpolation and synchronization of multiple animators.

Here is the link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html